# Vue router: redirect according to the current url

Tags: vuejs3, routerlink, vue-router4

I have a link in a navbar, that leads to a page (a new component is loaded in the main but not the navbar)

```
<router-link to="/edit_profile"><fa icon="user-cog" /></router-link>
```

and I would like that once on this page, this same link brings back to the first page.

I tried this:

```
  beforeRouteEnter(route, redirect, next){
if(this.$route.path === "/"){
  next()
} else {
  redirect('/')
} },
```

but it doesn't work.
Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: I duplicated the router-link with a condition regarding the path of the route.

```
<router-link v-if="$route.path == '/'" to="/edit_profile"><fa icon="user-cog" /></router-link>
<router-link v-if="$route.path != '/'" to="/"><fa icon="user-cog" /></router-link>
```

This is certainly not the most elegant solution. If anyone has a better one...